# How do refactor code for I amTypeError - Angular ^5.0

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angular

I am getting TypeError when trying to implement this angular code. It generates error around Class({constructor: function() {}}).  I have been pointed to this (https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/cac130eff9b9cb608f2308ae40c42c9cd1850c4d) but not sure how to implement solution.

I would love some help understand an alternative as I am new to this coding stuff.

This is from a book that I recently purchased about using rails, angular 
and postgres together.  thanks.

```
import "hello_angular/polyfills";

import { Component, NgModule    } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule          } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule            } from "@angular/forms";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

var CustomerSearchComponent = Component({
  selector: "shine-customer-search",
  template: '\
<header> \
  <h1 class="h2">Customer Search</h1> \
</header> \
  '
}).Class({
  constructor: function() {
  }
});

var CustomerAppModule = NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ CustomerSearchComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ CustomerSearchComponent ]
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the information in the link above, you have to define your component as `class` and decorate it with the `@Component` decorator.

```
@Component({
  selector: "shine-customer-search",
  template: '\
<header> \
  <h1 class="h2">Customer Search</h1> \
</header> \
  '
})
export class CustomerSearchComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

<strike>You also have to use `typescript`. As you tagged your question with `javascript` this may be an issue for you.</strike>

Your module will look like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ CustomerSearchComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ CustomerSearchComponent ]
})
export class CustomerAppModule { }
```

Comment: **You also have to use typescript**, no, that's not true ;)